# Firestore custom document data mapping

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, google-cloud-firestore, mapping

[Firestore Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6JK4.png)

I have the following data structure in Firestore. I am having a hard time mapping it to my ios app. I am using Swift. Could anyone provide the codable struct or something?

```
struct CartModel: Codable {

    let cart: [CartItemModel]
   
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case cart
    }    
}

extension CartModel{
    static var dummyCartData : CartModel {
        .init(cart: [CartItemModel.dummyCartData])
    }
}


struct CartItemModel: Codable {
    let brand: String
    let itemDescription: String
    let image: String
    let selection: [UserSelection]
    let title:String    
   
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        
        case brand
        case itemDescription = "description"
        case image
        case selection
        case title

    }
}


extension CartItemModel{
    static var dummyCartData : CartItemModel {

        .init(brand: "gucci",
              itemDescription: "adidas",
              image: "yeezy",
              selection: [UserSelection.dummyData],
              title: "123")
    }
}


struct UserSelection: Codable, Equatable{
    var size :String
    var count : Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case size = "size"
        case count
    }

}

extension UserSelection{

    static var dummyData : UserSelection {

        .init(size: "XS11", count: 20)
    }
}


    docRef.getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            return
        }

        if let snapshot = snapshot, snapshot.exists {
            print(snapshot.data())
        let products = try! snapshot.data(as: CartModel.self)
            print(products)
       
        }
    }
```

Firestore returns

```
Optional(["cart": <__NSArrayM 0x600002979380>(
{
    brand = Nike;
    description = "Find the Jordan Point Lane at . ";
    image = "https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/f105dd55-53d0-4a50-b43a-55bd9231c658/jordan-point-lane-mens-shoes-PPMHdC.png";
    selection =     {
        count = 1;
        size = "";
    };
    title = "Jordan Point Lane Men's Shoes";
}
)
])
```

Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "cart", intValue: nil),

_FirestoreKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "selection", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Not an array", underlyingError: nil))

Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "cart", intValue: nil), _FirestoreKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "selection", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Not an array", underlyingError: nil))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, `selection` is not an array in the Firestore document, but you've defined it as one in your model.

Change `let selection: [UserSelection]` to `let selection: UserSelection`